# Dit-on plutôt "Je caresse des projets ambitieux avec toi" ou "Je caresse des projets ambitieux et tu en fais partie" ?

Tags: formulation

Pour faire comprendre à notre conjointe qu'elle occupe une place de premier plan dans notre vie et qu'elle la gardera pour longtemps.

Comment: Personnellement, j'utilise "envisage" au lieu de "caresse", mais ces 2 expressions peuvent marcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

À mon point de vue, dans tous les cas la seconde forme est d'un meilleur style. « Avec » a quelque chose de vague selon mon appréhension de ce type de construction et "et tu en fais partie » semble me parler plus nettement. La première forme n'élimine pas la possibilité que l'acte de caresser soit considéré comme partagé et un contexte peut être construit, je crois, dans lequel il y aura une ambigüité à laquelle seule la précision du contexte étant apportée dans la suite pourra pallier. Il existe aussi la possible interprétation de projets dans lesquels le locuteur n'aura pas une participation mais sera tout simplement un compagnon, ou bien n'est pour l'instant qu'une inspiration.

*Ces deux autres interprétations*

- Je caresse des projets ambitieux avec toi ;  n'oublions pas cependant que c'est n'est que toi qui puisse fournir la plus grande partie des moyens et donc une plus grande partie des décisions te revient.
- Je caresse des projets ambitieux avec toi ;  tu est mon inspiration, ma raison de croire en ce que je fais.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux sont grammaticalement corrects. Cependant, si c’est pour votre femme, je privilégierai le « ... et tu en fait partie » car cela insiste sur sa présence.